# React: why the valueof props !!!*change*¡¡¡?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, web, web-applications

i'm still learning React so i don't understand the behavior yet.
when the application begin the props value = undefined, but a few milisecond recive the props from index.js.... why this happens? and how should prevent this? thnaks for your answers.
(i'm showing in console)

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

class Apps extends Component{
  state ={
    posts : []
  }

  async componentDidMount (){
    const peticion = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    const data = await peticion.json();
    this.setState((state) =>({
      posts : data
    }));
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <App posts={this.state}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Apps />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import propTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class App extends Component {

  render (){
    console.log(this.props)

    return(
      <div>
        dialogo
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const comment = {
  background : 'grey',
  border: '5px solid red',
  borderRadius : ' black',
}
const btnDelete = {
  cursor : 'pointer',
  background : 'red',
  fontSize : '2rem',
  borderRadius : '50px',
  float : 'right'
}
App.propTypes = {
  props : propTypes.array.isRequired
}
```

Comment: I just tried this and there is no undefined being logged . https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-hill-downf

Comment: u sure?, cause i see it in the console

Answer (score 0):

You should drill the component in index.js with the props

and PropType should be object not array.

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-lamport-pqj7x

hope this helps

[image: No Console Error]